# Get values of _.groupBy

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a problem with JavaScript. The code is as follows:

```
var myDB = [
    { xCounter: 'positive', day: 'first' }, 
    { xCounter: 'positive', day: 'second' }
];

var days = _.groupBy(myDB, 'day');
```

How can I get the first, second, third... value of "days"?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example of what's inside the myDB variable?

Comment: Hi @Brunt, here's an example: myDB = [{ "xCounter": "positive", "day": "first" }, { "xCounter": "positive", "day": "second" }];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the example you gave:

```
var myDB =  [{ "xCounter": "positive", "day": "first" }, { "xCounter": "positive", "day": "second" }];
```

Using the `groupBy` method, you'll get the following result in the `days` variable:

```
{
  first: [{ "xCounter": "positive", "day": "first" }],
  second: [{ "xCounter": "positive", "day": "second" }]
}
```

To go through this result, you can use the following snippet:

```
for (var day in days) {
  if (days.hasOwnProperty(day)) {
    // do something with 'day' (which will take tha values 'first' and 'second')
    // and 'days[day]' (which is an array of {xCounter: X, day: Y} objects)
  }
}
```

PS: I'd suggest using Lodash instead of Underscore if possible (https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.1#groupBy) as Lodash development is more active, but that's my opinion ;)